# pywintypes.error: in pywinauto (1460, 'SetCursorPos', 'This operation returned because the timeout period expired.')

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to automate one software to perform one operation many times, My code is given below.

```
import os
import pywinauto, time
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import mouse
from pywinauto import keyboard

app = application.Application()


def my_function(fname):
    print("Start",fname)
    app.start("C:\\CAPEC\\ICAS\\bin\\Convert2MG1.exe", wait_for_idle=False)
    time.sleep(1)
    app.Convert2MG1.set_focus()
    app.Convert2MG1.maximize()
    app.Convert2MG1.menu_select("Tools->Batch Estimations..")
    pywinauto.mouse.click(coords=(914, 715))
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.send_keys(fname)
    time.sleep(1)
    pywinauto.mouse.click(coords=(1114, 659))
    pywinauto.mouse.click(coords=(1013, 717))
    time.sleep(1)
    pywinauto.mouse.click(coords=(1022, 659))
    time.sleep(1)
```

##all these are used to remove failed pop-ups many times.

```
pywinauto.mouse.click(coords=(1022, 659))
    time.sleep(.2)

    print("Done ", fname)


for filename in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\Tox\\tcm2'):
    my_function(filename)
```

the code runs fine for few times but I am seingone error I have hardly seen before.

List of errors I am facing.

```
C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py:1085: UserWarning: 32-bit application should be automated using 32-bit Python (you use 64-bit Python)
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Tox/36.py", line 55, in <module>
    my_function(filename)
  File "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Tox/36.py", line 38, in my_function
    pywinauto.mouse.click(coords=(1022, 659))
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\mouse.py", line 229, in click
    _perform_click_input(button=button, coords=coords)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\mouse.py", line 137, in _perform_click_input
    _set_cursor_pos((coords[0], coords[1]))
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\mouse.py", line 64, in _set_cursor_pos
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\mouse.py", line 59, in _set_cursor_pos
    win32api.SetCursorPos(coords)
pywintypes.error: (1460, 'SetCursorPos', 'This operation returned because the timeout period expired.')
```

Comment: Have you tried to do `try-except` to see if it happens again and again at the same point or with some probability.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.

Comment: And what? Is it working now?